# wordpress, mulitsite missing wp_options table

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have one strange request here, one of my client's WordPress multi-site environment site needs to migrate to another server and change domain name but when I checked the database the main wp-options table does not exist there.

And am I not able to do migration of this setup getting blank page

Can anyone suggest on this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Impossible (Table most probably **deleted** or **you don't't see it**)
2. define WP_DEBUG as true, WP_DEBUG_LOG or WP_DEBUG_SHOW (on your choice) to see what's happening.

Comment: But Previous developer is saying their sites are running fine without that table.

Comment: or.. its a not a wordpress. its not hard to actually "check" code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. I just deleted this table and the site stopped working. It shows the error: Error establishing a database connection

It doesn't have to be called wp_options though. The prefix could be different. So it could be something_options. The prefix is defined in the wp_config.php file.

If you are viewing the tables in phpMyAdmin you can enter _options in the text field for filtering the tables. This should find it.

If you mean that it doesn't exist on the new server only, then the database might not have been imported correctly. See if it exists on the old server.